# How to build function that accepts multidimensional array as parameters, receiving incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, gcc-warning

```
double imprimirValores(char dadosHotelaria[], int n);

int main( void )
{
    char dadosHotelaria2 [1][3][50] = 
    {
        {
            "unidadeid1", "joao fernandes", "quartoExecutivo"
        };           
    };
    imprimirValores(dadosHotelaria2, 1);
  }

double imprimirValores(char dadosHotelaria[][3][50], int n)
{ 
    return 0;
}
```

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'imprimirValores' from incompatible pointer type ((imprimir valores))

Comment: Functions need to be defined or declared before they are called.

Comment: Is the code you show a proper [mcve]? Is there something you don't show us? If this is indeed your complete code, then the problem is that you have forgotten to declare the `imprimirValores` function before you called it.

Comment: @dbush That would cause a warning about implicit declarations. So I think he just didn't show us the declaration.

Comment: If you *have* a proper declaration of `imprimirValores` then you need to show it to us, and to make the code a proper [mcve]. And check that the declaration matches the definition.

Comment: The declaration needs to match the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the function to take a `char []` as the first parameter:

```
double imprimirValores(char dadosHotelaria[], int n);
```

But define it to take a `char [][3][50]`:

```
double imprimirValores(char dadosHotelaria[][3][50], int n)
{ 
    return 0;
}
```

The declaration of a function must match its definition:

```
double imprimirValores(char dadosHotelaria[][3][50], int n);
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a few suggestions as people hinted at in the comments (and one syntax error).  but this works:

```
    double imprimirValores(char dadosHotelaria[][3][50], int n)
    { 
       return 0;
    }

    int main( void )
    {
      char dadosHotelaria2 [1][3][50] = 
        {
            {
           "unidadeid1", "joao fernandes", "quartoExecutivo"
            }
        };
        imprimirValores(dadosHotelaria2, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For starters there is a syntax error in the array declaration

```
char dadosHotelaria2 [1][3][50] = 
{
    {
        "unidadeid1", "joao fernandes", "quartoExecutivo"
    };
    ^^           
};
```

You may not place a semicolon within the braced-init list.

You may place a comma like

```
char dadosHotelaria2 [1][3][50] = 
{
    {
        "unidadeid1", "joao fernandes", "quartoExecutivo"
    },
    ^^           
};
```

But of course it will be better to write without the comma like

```
char dadosHotelaria2 [1][3][50] = 
{
    {
        "unidadeid1", "joao fernandes", "quartoExecutivo"
    }
    ^^           
};
```

When the compiler parses this statement

```
imprimirValores(dadosHotelaria2, 1);
```

it assumes that the function return type is `int` for compatibility with old versions of C though starting from the C 99 Standard you may not use function names without their preliminary declarations.

But actually the function has the return type `double`. So the compiler issues an error.

You should declare the function before using its name in main as for example

```
double imprimirValores(char dadosHotelaria[][3][50], int n);

int main( void )
{
    //...
```